# Wordpress feed parameters for specific dates

Tags: wordpress, rss

Is it possible to query stock wordpress blog to return RSS feed of items between dates A and B?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to an answer to this and came across the following note in the [WordPress Codex WP_Query class reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters)

> Note: The queries above return posts for a specific date period in
>   history, i.e. "Posts from X year, X month, X day". They are unable to
>   fetch posts from a timespan relative to the present, so queries like
>   "Posts from the last 30 days" or "Posts from the last year" are not
>   possible with a basic query, and require use of the posts_where filter
>   to be completed.

So as of Wordpress 3.4.2, this is still not possibly using a feed URL with suitable query parameters.

You will either need to use post_where if you are coding for Wordpress or else create your own script to work-around this by checking the dates within the pubDate elements in the feed XML.